# Analyse the importance of the features for predicting dependent variable .?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, statistical-significance

I have a dataset with 10,000 observations. 19 Independent and 1 dependent variable(Customer Response). I want to Analyse the importance of the features for predicting customer response(dependent variable).

The dependent variable is the Binary Categorical variable, of 19 Independent Variables, 17 are categorical ( all Nominal ) and 2 are continuous.

How can I find features that are important for predicting customer response(dependent variable) to include them for predicting Customer Response.?

Comment: Please see our threads on [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic%2bregression?tab=Votes).  Another popular technique is the [Random Forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=random%20forest%20importan*).

Comment: One option is [tag:boruta], which typically uses [tag:random-forest] but can use any estimator that yields a metric of variable importance.